# How to hide a row when a new one was requested to be shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have formed this [Datatable | jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs6qemh4/1/) which extends a row when the row is pressed by user.

Approach is very simple:

```
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row( this );

    if(row.child.isShown()){
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
           }
    });

    $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'td button', function (){

    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row( this );

    alert(row); 

    });
```

However I need only 1 row to be opened. So, when user wants to open another row, I want the first one to be hidden.

UPDATE: The problem is that the ability to close a row by pressing on it have to be stored, I mean if user don't press other rows just press on a first one, it has to toogle(open/close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function () {

var a = $('#table_id').DataTable();

function format ( d ) {

    var editform = '<form id="newtry" action="javascript:alert( "success!" );"> <div class="form-row align-items-center"><div class="col-auto"><label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="'+d[0]+'"></div><div class="col-auto"><label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label><div class="input-group mb-2"><div class="input-group-prepend"><div class="input-group-text">@</div></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username"></div></div><div class="col-auto"></div><div class="col-auto"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" >Submit</button></div> </div></form>';

    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return editform;
}

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){

// check if clicked on shown tab
    if (!$( this ).hasClass( "waf" ) ) {

    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row( this );

    if(row.child.isShown()){
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
          $(".shown").removeClass("shown");
            $(".waf").remove();
    } else {

      $(".shown").removeClass("shown");
            $(".waf").remove();


        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
         row.child().addClass('waf'); 
           }
    }
});

    $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'td button', function (){

    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row( this );
});
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Hfwthorn/3y8qe6b7/8/

Comment: Excellent! That's exact that I had looking for. Thank you for your kind support!

Answer (score 0):

First hide all the child of `td` -

Working fiddle -https://jsfiddle.net/n20z4tyu/.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
        var a = $('#table_id').DataTable();
            function format ( d ) {
                var editform = '<form id="newtry" action="javascript:alert( "success!" );"> <div class="form-row align-items-center"><div class="col-auto"><label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="'+d[0]+'"></div><div class="col-auto"><label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label><div class="input-group mb-2"><div class="input-group-prepend"><div class="input-group-text">@</div></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username"></div></div><div class="col-auto"></div><div class="col-auto"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" >Submit</button></div> </div></form>';
                // `d` is the original data object for the row
                return editform;
            }

        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
        $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
            var tr = $(this);
            var row = a.row( this );
            const childrens = $('#table_id tr td').children();
            childrens.hide();
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        });
    
        $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'td button', function (){
        var tr = $(this);
        var row = a.row( this );
        alert(row); 
    });

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Unfortunatelly this doesn't work proper, because Row not close fully - you can try to press first one again and it will not open.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

It will close the other open rows but not close current row on click (toggle)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var a = $('#table_id').DataTable();


  function format(d) {

    var editform = '<form id="newtry" action="javascript:alert( "success!" );"> <div class="form-row align-items-center"><div class="col-auto"><label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="' + d[0] + '"></div><div class="col-auto"><label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label><div class="input-group mb-2"><div class="input-group-prepend"><div class="input-group-text">@</div></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username"></div></div><div class="col-auto"></div><div class="col-auto"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" >Submit</button></div> </div></form>';

    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return editform;
  }


  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var tr = $(this);
    tr.closest("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {
      row = a.row(this);
      if ($(this).is(tr)) {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.show().addClass('shown');
      } else {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
      }
    });
  });

  $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'td button', function() {

    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row(this);

    alert(row);

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">


<table id="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. It works almost perfect, however you can't to close a row just pressing on it. :(

Comment: That was not part of the initial spec - I do not have time to fix that now.

Comment: I understand. Appreciate you have spend your time helping me.